# migrating user profiles when upgrading from pentaho server version x.x to 8.1

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

In pentaho server x.x i have user profiles like useraccount names and passwords and their own repository. How Do I migrate them when updating pentaho server to 8.1

I am sorry if its lame question, but I am not very skilled in web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x.x requirement is tricky. It’ll probably depend a lot on which version you’re currently on, as changes were made throughout multiple versions.

But normally your user profiles are in the hibernate database, which is either mysql, hypersonic or postgres (depending on version and wherher CE or EE), or is something customised.

There you’ll find the relevant tables with usernames, encrypted passwords, roles, etc.

Depending on version you may be able to import the whole hibernate db (and hope for the best), but you may need to start anew and just import manually the bits you actually need